# Content inside CDATA is not displayed properly when processed through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, cdata

I have an XML document with some sample content like this:

```
<someTag>
 <![CDATA[Hello World]]>
</someTag>
```

I'm parsing the above XML in JavaScript. When I try access and render the *Hello World* text using `xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("someTag")[0].childNodes[0].textContent` all I get was a blank text on screen.

The code is not returning `undefined` or any error messages. So I guess the code is properly accessing the message. But due to `CDATA`, it is not rendering properly on screen.

Anyway to fix the issue and get the Hello World out of this xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running Firefox, maybe [this](http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2007/04/accessing-cdata-section-in-xml-dom-from.html) is the issue you're having. The behavior looks very similair... The following might do the trick:

```
xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("someTag")[0].childNodes[1].textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that Firefox's behaviour is absolutely correct. `someTag` has three children:

- A `Text` node containing the whitespace between the `<someTag>` and `<!CDATA`. This is one newline and one space;
- the `CDATASection` node itself;
- another whitespace `Text` node containing the single newline character between the end of the CDATA and the close-tag.

It's best not to rely closely on what combination of text and CDATA nodes might exist in an element if all you want is the text value inside it. Just call `textContent` on `<someTag>` *itself* and you'll get all the combined text content: `'\n Hello World\n'`. (You can `.trim()` this is you like.)